# How to add an active css class to current page but not for bookmark menu item

Tags: wordpress

I have a bookmark item in main navigation which is navigating on the home page itself. the problem is, `nav_menu_css_class` function highlighting two items in navigation at a time. (e.g Home and Pricing)

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {

    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){

        $classes[] = 'active ';

    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about this but is your home the main parent of all the pages ?

Comment: yes, home page is main page in navigation